# Meaning of "judicial emphasis"

Tags: meaning-in-context, adjectives, adjective-phrases

(From *The Wrecker* by Robert Louis Stevenson and Lloyd Osbourne, Chapter XVII, published 1892)[1][passage 271](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Wrecker_(Stevenson)/Chapter_17)

> “Yes; I think I understand,” said he. “Suppose I pass you my word that, whatever may have occurred, there were excuses—great excuses—I may say, very great?”
>
> “It would have weight with me, doctor,” I replied.
>
> “I may go further,” he pursued. “Suppose I had been there, or you had been there. After a certain event had taken place, it's a grave question what we might have done—it's even a question what we could have done—ourselves. Or take me. I will be plain with you, and own that I am in possession of the facts. You have a shrewd guess how I have acted in that knowledge. May I ask you to judge from the character of my action, something of the nature of that knowledge, which I have no call, nor yet no title, to share with you?”
>
> **I cannot convey a sense of the rugged conviction and judicial emphasis of Dr. Urquart's speech**. To those who did not hear him, it may appear as if he fed me on enigmas; to myself, who heard, I seemed to have received a lesson and a compliment.
>
> “I thank you,” I said. “I feel you have said as much as possible, and more than I had any right to ask. I take that as a mark of confidence, which I will try to deserve. I hope, sir, you will let me regard you as a friend.”
>
> He evaded my proffered friendship with a blunt proposal to rejoin the mess . . .

I've looked up the meaning of 'judicial' in the dictionaries https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/judicial but I'm not certain what is meant in this context. In particular the combination with the word 'emphasis' troubles me. Is there a synonym?

Comment: It's not functioning as a phrase. "Emphasis" just refers to his tone of voice. And this emphasis is "judicial." Several of the definitions on the page you linked to include variations on "like a judge," which seems most appropriate here.

Comment: Voting to close; although you had difficulty finding the right dictionary definition, this is a simple "dictionary-definition" question.

Comment: I’m not so sure, @AndyBonner, that it means judgelike. I’d say it simply means reflecting sound judgment.

Comment: I might perhaps prefer 'judicious': _having, exercising, or characterized by good or discriminating judgment; wise, sensible, or well-advised_ However, it's not 1892 and I'm not RLS. However OED gives _That has or shows sound judgement; judicious. **Obs**._

Comment: I considered that it's an archaic substitution for _judicious_, but decided given the context that "marked by the solemnity and weight that a judge's speech might show" was more likely. Hard to say without a larger context and knowing the character and their motivation.

Comment: @AndyBonner - I remember, at the age of 30, asking someone what 'hieratic' meant. This was before the Internet, and I didn't have a dictionary to hand. It was in a newspaper article about the verbal manner of Ian McDonald, the Ministry of Defence spokesman during the Falklands war.

Comment: I would understand **judicial emphasis** there to refer to the nuanced precision with which Urquart defines the salient elements of his hypothetical.

Comment: Thank you for helping :)

Answer (score 1):

The Imperial Dictionary by John Ogilvie (1885) has this:

*(Meanings of "judicial")*

. . .

**7.(obsolete) Judicious.**

*Her brains a quiver of jests, and she does dart them abroad with that sweet, loose, and judicial action.* B. Jonson.

[judicial](https://archive.org/details/b22652000_0002/page/670/mode/2up?q=%22judicial%22)

Answer (score -1):

When you put **emphasis** on something, or emphasize something, you are drawing attention to it as an important component of your thought. As you might imagine, there are many different kinds of emphasis.

The word **judicial** is used as an ordinary adjective that describes the kind of emphasis. If you write about a *judicial proceeding*, you're using the word in a similar fashion to describe a type of proceeding. There's really nothing out of the ordinary here.